# ContainerRequestFilter randomly giving null

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0

I have a Spring 4 + Jersey 2 web application which uses JWT for authentication.

I'm using a `ContainerRequestFilter` to intercept each call and check if the request has the correct `Authorization` token:

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.Claim;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

import my.beans.User;

@Provider
public class JWTFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(JWTFilter.class);


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        LOG.debug("JWT Filter");
        String authorization = context.getHeaderString("Authorization");
        if(authorization != null) {
            String jwtToken = authorization.replaceAll(".*Bearer\\s+", "");
            DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(jwtToken);
            Map<String, Claim> claims = jwt.getClaims();
            String userid = claims.get("userid").asString();

            if(userid != null) {
                User user = loadUser(userid);

                // save user to request, so that it gets
                context.setProperty("loggedUser", user); 

                LOG.debug("User found: " + user);
            }
        } else {
            LOG.debug("JWT missing");
        }
    }

    private User loadUser(String userid) {
        // loads a User object
    }
}
```

I then have a `BaseResource` class which has a `getLoggedUser()` method that retrieves data from `ContainerRequestContext`:

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import my.beans.User;

public class BaseResource {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(BaseResource.class);

    @Context
    private ContainerRequestContext context;

    public User getLoggedUser() {
        User u = (User) context.getProperty("loggedUser");
        LOG.debug("getLoggedUser(): " + u);
        return u;
    }

}
```

The `BaseResource` class is extended by all Jersey resources.

This is one of the resources I have:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import my.beans.User;

@Component
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource extends BaseResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Path("/")
    public Response test() {
        User u = getLoggedUser();

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

If I try executing this resource, I get this log:

```
DEBUG: JWT Filter
DEBUG: User found: my.beans.User@4e7fb700
DEBUG: getLoggedUser(): my.beans.User@4e7fb700
```

It seems to work.

If I start refreshing the page again and again, this happens:

```
DEBUG: JWT Filter
DEBUG: User found: my.beans.User@4c0bea44
DEBUG: getLoggedUser(): my.beans.User@4c0bea44
DEBUG: JWT Filter
DEBUG: User found: my.beans.User@6ac29f24
DEBUG: getLoggedUser(): my.beans.User@6ac29f24
DEBUG: JWT Filter
DEBUG: User found: my.beans.User@668b07db
DEBUG: getLoggedUser(): null
DEBUG: JWT Filter
DEBUG: User found: my.beans.User@42fc180c
DEBUG: getLoggedUser(): my.beans.User@42fc180c
```

The third time, the user **is found** in the `JWTFilter` class, but comes `null` inside the controller. It's weird because the filter puts it inside the `ContainerRequestContext`, so the issue should not happen. It seems that sometime the `ContainerRequestContext` is unable to hold data, or loses it while reaching the controller.

What is happening here? Why do I randomly get `null` objects when calling `ContainerRequestContest#getProperty`? Should I do this differently?

It's worth mentioning that my filter is a `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter`. Should I use a `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from filter to resource, try to set http header in filter class so that you can get in resource class using header param

Comment: Can a header contain a java object?

Comment: You can convert json object to string and add in header.Once you got data back in resource convert back to json object /map in bean class using jackson mapper.

Comment: It's not a json object, it's a java object. It seems an unnecessary overhead to me to convert each time the object to pass it as header. The `ContainerRequestContext` should work here, I should not have the need of using headers.